# Flutter firebase sendSignInLinkToEmail not sending email and reporting any errors iOS

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication, firebase-dynamic-links

Hi I have followed these steps https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/ios/receive and
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/email-link-auth#before_you_begin.

However when I come to run

```
FirebaseAuth.instance.sendSignInLinkToEmail(
                  email: "my email",
                  actionCodeSettings: ActionCodeSettings(
                    url: "https://myapp.firebaseapp.com",
                    iOS: {
                      "bundleId": "my bundleId"
                    },
                    android: {
                      "packageName": "mypackagename",
                      "installApp": true,
                      "minimumVersion": "21"
                    },
                    handleCodeInApp: true,

                  )
              )
```

However the no error occurs and no email is sent to my email address.

I have wasted 2.5 days of my life. Any suggestions will help, thanks.

Comment: `https://myapp.firebaseapp.com` --> is this url whitelisted in the Firebase Console list of authorized domains, which can be found by going to the Sign-in method tab (Authentication -> Sign-in method)?

Comment: @ShababbKarim yes that’s a default authorised domain

Comment: @ShababbKarim I have tried it on my android phone and it works so it is not a firebase server side issue but an iOS app issue

Comment: have you checked in your spam folder?

Answer (score 3):

I was also facing the same issue yesterday and after multiple trials i found out that in ActionCodeSettings, url you're passing should be whitelisted in firebase sign-in method.

For example, if you've added domain name example.com in firebase sign-in method then url in ActionCodeSettings must have https://example.com/... and the rest paramter will be same as it is.

For whitelisting your domain,
Go to Firebase Console > Authentication > Sign-in Method > Add domain
[click on add domain to whitelist your domain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XSoQq.png)

Comment: Even after whitelisting the domain, signin link is not sent

Comment: Small update on where to find the _Authorized Domains_: Firebase Console > Authentication > Settings.

Comment: I'm using `localhost`. It's an authorized domain. My emails are still not being sent. I'm not getting errors when making the method call.

Comment: I did get the email in my gmail account. It was marked as spam. The outlook email address didn't receive the email, not even in spam.